# Accessing 2D Array elements in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

```
{
   "Name1" : "Value1",
   "Name2" : "Value2",
   "Name3" : [{
          "Elem1" : "String"
    }]
}
```

I want
`"Elem1" : "String"`
(OR)
`"String"`
as an output. Tried several aggregate and find functions in Mongo Shell.

Comment: please provide what all you have tried. no spoon feeding here

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.find({"Name3":{$elemMatch:{"Elem1":"specificValue"}}},{"Name3.$":1})
```

Try this query, $ operator return the first matching document of array